# why this not compile?

Tags: java, compilation

I have these files:

```
c:\MY_SOURCES\AClient.java
c:\MY_SOURCES\Pluto.java
c:\MY_SOURCES\com\Classes\Pluto.class
```

Into AClient.java I have

```
import com.Classes.*;
Pluto p = new Pluto();
```

When I compile the file with:

```
javac -classpath . AClient.java
```

the compiler tell me that it cannot access `Pluto` as bad source file `Pluto.java` ... but if I move `Pluto.java` away from `c:\MY_SOURCES` it compiles.

Comment: Please fix your message. In one place you specify `MY_JAVA_SOURCES` in other `MY_SOURCES`. Also I was not able to understand where each file is. Please write a full path to **each** file and your compiling options.

Comment: Ok... I have edited the question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source folder should mirror your package structure. If it does not javac gets confused. Ideally your compiled .class folder should be in a different root to your source folder.

So

```
c:\MY_SOURCES\AClient.java (assuming in the default package)
c:\MY_SOURCES\com\Classes\Pluto.java

c:\MY_COMPILED\com\Classes\Pluto.class

javac -classpath=c:\MY_COMPILED -d 
c:\MY_COMPILED\ c:\MY_SOURCES\AClient.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reiterating...

```
C:\MY_SOURCES\AClient.java
C:\MY_SOURCES\com\Classes\Pluto.java
```

Assuming AClient.java contains...

```
import com.Classes.*;

public class AClient {
   Pluto p = new Pluto();
}
```

This compilation does works

```
C:\MY_SOURCES\javac *.java
```

Comment: not correct:
C:\MY_SOURCES\com\Classes\Pluto.class not Pluto.java that is into C:\MY_SOURCES

Comment: post the content of Pluto.java or exact error... or see if you move the Pluto.java to com/Classes folder. If both Pluto.java and Pluto.class are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you introduced an error in your Pluto file. When you try to compile AClient it will also try to compile Pluto (since it's used by AClient) and will hit the error. If you remove Pluto.java you have the class file there from a previous (successful) compilation, and it uses that, and it works. You should check Pluto.java and see if it compiles by itself, or if there are any other problems with it.